# How to Press OK on a save as dialog when downloading a PDF from a website

Tags: pdf, webdriver

Im using Selenium WebDriver in C# and have so far managed the following steps;
Go to web page, Open the PDF, Press download button.

```
{
[TestFixture]
public class DownloadPDF
{
    private static IWebDriver driver = null;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors = null;
    private string baseURL;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();          
        baseURL = ("http://pdfobject.com/");
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(5000));

    }
    [Test]
    public void main()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/pdf/pdfobject.pdf#view=FitH&pagemode=thumbs&search=pdfobject&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=1");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("download")).Click();
    }

}
}
```

I now get a save dialog that has 2 radio buttons (open with and Save file), and a check box (do this automatically in the future)

The default selected option is save file, so I want to check on 'do this automatically from now on', and then press OK.

Ive seen some Java examples of how this could be achived, but so far I have found nothing in C#.

Ideally Id like to download straight to a file location on my machine if thats possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my work I usually use [UIAutomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) library to interact with desktop apps. Also for that you can use some frameworks which were developed especially for such purposes (e.g. White). But for me, easier write my own using winapi, uiautomation. You can wrap your dialog and expose it's elements so from test it will be easy to use it anywhere. Example of such code below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DownloadPDF
{
    private static IWebDriver driver = null;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors = null;
    private string baseURL;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();          
        baseURL = ("http://pdfobject.com/");
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(5000));

    }
    [Test]
    public void main()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/pdf/pdfobject.pdf#view=FitH&pagemode=thumbs&search=pdfobject&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=1");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("download")).Click();
        var window = new Window("your window name");
        window.OpenWithBtn.Click();
        window.Save.Click();
    }

}

public class Window
    {
        private readonly string _windowName;
        private AutomationElement _window;

        public Window(string windowName)
        {
            _windowName = windowName;
            _window = GetWindow(_windowName);
        }

        private AutomationElement GetWindow(string windowName)
        {
            return UIAutomationElements.FindDescedantByCondition(AutomationElement.RootElement,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, windowName));
        }

        private AutomationElement GetElement(string elementName)
        {
            if (_window == null)
                _window = GetWindow(_windowName);
            return UIAutomationElements.FindDescedantByCondition(_window,
                new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.RadioButton),
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, elementName)));
        }

        public Button OpenWithBtn
        {
            get
            {
                return new Button(GetElement("Open With..."));
            }
        }

        public Button Save
        {
            get
            {
                return new Button(GetElement("Open With..."));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Button
    {
        private readonly AutomationElement _btnElement;

        public Button(AutomationElement btnElement)
        {
            _btnElement = btnElement;
        }

        public void Click()
        {
            //perform click using winapi or invoke button if 'InvokePattern' available for it
            var invokePattern = _btnElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern; 
            invokePattern.Invoke();
        }
    }

public class UIAutomationElements
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Find descedant of specified element by it's index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Main element in which search should be performed.</param>
    /// <param name="condition">Condition by wchich element will be identified. See <see cref="Condition"/>, <see cref="PropertyCondition"/> etc...</param>
    /// <param name="itemIndex">Index of element which should found</param>
    /// <returns>Founded element as <see cref="AutomationElement"/> with specified index</returns>
    public static AutomationElement FindDescedantByCondition(AutomationElement element, Condition condition, int itemIndex)
    {
        var result = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condition);

        return result[itemIndex];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find all descedants in the main element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Main element in whick search should be performed.</param>
    /// <param name="condition">Condition by wchich element will be identified. See <see cref="Condition"/>, <see cref="PropertyCondition"/> etc...</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="AutomationElementCollection"/></returns>
    public static AutomationElementCollection FindDescedantsByCondition(AutomationElement element, Condition condition)
    {
        var result = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condition);
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find descedant by specified condition
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">Main element in which search should be performed.</param>
    /// <param name="condition">Condition by wchich element will be identified.
    ///  See <see cref="Condition"/>, <see cref="PropertyCondition"/> etc...</param>
    /// <returns>Element as <see cref="AutomationElement"/></returns>
    public static AutomationElement FindDescedantByCondition(AutomationElement element, Condition condition)
    {
        var result = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condition);

        return result;
    }
}
```

To perform click you can use on winapi methods. SOme of the solutions described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cc154e7-8918-42db-8a76-deac191e70e6/clicking-on-a-tree-item-with-uiautomation). Hope this will help.

P.S. if you need simply click on OK button, you don't need to wrap anything. Just find dialog and button inside it and perform click =)

Comment: Hi Andrey, Iwas able to add a reference to UIAutomationClient, and do using System.Windows.Automation;   However, this didnt seem to resolve UIAutomationElements?  Have tried adding 'System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement' but I dont get this option - is there something else im missing.  Please note im kinda learning c# as I go, so I appreciate this is probably quite trivial.  thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Sorry =) it's my fault ). I always use that class and forget that it's simple wrapper around UIAutomation =). Answer has been updated with new class =). Sorry again. P.S. You'll need to add reference to UIAutomationTypes.dll too.

Comment: Thanks Andry - I got the code in and building with the additional reference.  Will spend some time in understanding what the code is doing, and look into how to implement the winapi method.  Will post back with an update on progress.  Thanks agin.

Comment: To find out name of elements, their clases etc you can use UISpy tool.

Comment: Hi Andry - managed to get the code working with the following code put into the TODO bit:  var invokePattern = _btnElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
            invokePattern.Invoke(); - didneed some extra help from a collegue, but got there in the end - thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Now looking into getting adobe to file save to a location on my local machine.

Comment: Answer has been updated. Invoke pattern good, but unfortunately not all buttons implement that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the save dialog you mention is not part of the web page DOM, Selenium will not be able to do much.

You can use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to handle these situations. It is free, light weight and can handle basic windows and controls. Use it in your C# project by adding a reference to the Interop.AutoItX3Lib.dll.

Here are my wrapper classes to handle the AutoIt API:

```
namespace QA.AutoIt
{
    using System;
    using AutoItX3Lib;

    public class AutoItWindow
    {
        public static AutoItX3 AutoItDriver;
        public string Title;
        public string Text;

        public AutoItWindow(string windowTitle, string windowText = "")
        {
            AutoItDriver = new AutoItX3();;
            Title = windowTitle;
            Text = windowText;
        }

        public void Activate()
        {
            AutoItDriver.WinActivate(Title, Text);
        }
    }

    public class AutoItElement
    {
        private static AutoItX3 _au3;
        private AutoItWindow _parent;
        private string _controlID;

        public AutoItElement(AutoItWindow parentWindow, string controlID)
        {
            _au3 = AutoItWindow.AutoItDriver;
            _parent = parentWindow;
            _controlID = controlID;
        }

        public void Click(string button = "LEFT")
        {
            // Set the window active
            _parent.Activate();

            // Click on the control
            _au3.ControlClick(_parent.Title, _parent.Text, _controlID, button);
        }

        public void SendText(string textToSend)
        {
            // Set the window active
            _parent.Activate();

            // Send the specified text to the control
            _au3.ControlFocus(_parent.Title, _parent.Text, _controlID);
            _au3.ControlSend(_parent.Title, _parent.Text, _controlID, textToSend);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of uploading a file. Similar to what you're trying to achieve. I define a class that models the dialog UI with an OpenFile method to perform the required actions. The strings that identify the window and its child controls are easy to get with the AutoIt object spy tool.

```
public class FileOpenWindow : AutoItWindow
{
    #region Child Controls
    public AutoItElement FileNameEdit;
    public AutoItElement OKButton;
    #endregion

    public FileOpenWindow(string title = "Open", string text = "")
        : base(title, text)
    {
        FileNameEdit = new AutoItElement(this, "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]");
        OKButton = new AutoItElement(this, "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]");
    }

    public void OpenFile(string fileName)
    {
        // Wait for the window to appear then activate it
        WaitToAppear(30);
        Activate();

        // Enter in the filename and click OK to start upload
        FileNameEdit.SendText(fileName);
        OKButton.Click();

        // Wait for the window to disappear
        WaitToDisappear(30);
    }
}
```